# Why can't i get cmake to work with vcpkg in vs code without VS Generator

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code, cmake, vcpkg

My **DCMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE** option is set appropiately. Intellisense recognises the library that i am using and yet i can't seem to get it working.
Usually i get. If i don't set the target architecture it goes on to build without vcpkg. If i do try to set it it says that it is not supported by the genrator which is actually to be expected since in the **cmake --help** ony The VS generators have the **[Arch]** tag

**CmakeLists.txt**

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.10)

# set the project name
project(KeyHUD)
find_library()
# add the executable
add_executable(main main.cpp)
```

Comand 1 i tried and its output

```
PS D:\.WorkSpaces\KeyHUD> cmake -G "MinGW Makefile" -A=Win32 "-DCMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE=D:\.Installs\vcpkg\scripts\buildsystems\vcpkg.cmake" 
CMake Error: Could not create named generator MinGW Makefile

Generators
  Visual Studio 16 2019        = Generates Visual Studio 2019 project files.
                                 Use -A option to specify architecture.     
* Visual Studio 15 2017 [arch] = Generates Visual Studio 2017 project files.
                                 Optional [arch] can be "Win64" or "ARM".
  Visual Studio 14 2015 [arch] = Generates Visual Studio 2015 project files.
                                 Optional [arch] can be "Win64" or "ARM".
  Visual Studio 12 2013 [arch] = Generates Visual Studio 2013 project files.
                                 Optional [arch] can be "Win64" or "ARM".
  Visual Studio 11 2012 [arch] = Generates Visual Studio 2012 project files.
                                 Optional [arch] can be "Win64" or "ARM".
  Visual Studio 10 2010 [arch] = Generates Visual Studio 2010 project files.
                                 Optional [arch] can be "Win64" or "IA64".
  Visual Studio 9 2008 [arch]  = Generates Visual Studio 2008 project files.
                                 Optional [arch] can be "Win64" or "IA64".
  Borland Makefiles            = Generates Borland makefiles.
  NMake Makefiles              = Generates NMake makefiles.
  NMake Makefiles JOM          = Generates JOM makefiles.
  MSYS Makefiles               = Generates MSYS makefiles.
  MinGW Makefiles              = Generates a make file for use with
                                 mingw32-make.
  Unix Makefiles               = Generates standard UNIX makefiles.
  Green Hills MULTI            = Generates Green Hills MULTI files
                                 (experimental, work-in-progress).
  Ninja                        = Generates build.ninja files.
  Ninja Multi-Config           = Generates build-<Config>.ninja files.
  Watcom WMake                 = Generates Watcom WMake makefiles.
  CodeBlocks - MinGW Makefiles = Generates CodeBlocks project files.
  CodeBlocks - NMake Makefiles = Generates CodeBlocks project files.
  CodeBlocks - NMake Makefiles JOM
                               = Generates CodeBlocks project files.
  CodeBlocks - Ninja           = Generates CodeBlocks project files.
  CodeBlocks - Unix Makefiles  = Generates CodeBlocks project files.
  CodeLite - MinGW Makefiles   = Generates CodeLite project files.
  CodeLite - NMake Makefiles   = Generates CodeLite project files.
  CodeLite - Ninja             = Generates CodeLite project files.
  CodeLite - Unix Makefiles    = Generates CodeLite project files.
  Sublime Text 2 - MinGW Makefiles
                               = Generates Sublime Text 2 project files.
  Sublime Text 2 - NMake Makefiles
                               = Generates Sublime Text 2 project files.
  Sublime Text 2 - Ninja       = Generates Sublime Text 2 project files.
  Sublime Text 2 - Unix Makefiles
                               = Generates Sublime Text 2 project files.
```

Command 2 and its output

```
    PS D:\.WorkSpaces\KeyHUD\build> cmake "-DCMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE=D:\.Installs\vcpkg\scripts\buildsystems\vcpkg.cmake" ..
CMake Warning at D:/.Installs/vcpkg/scripts/buildsystems/vcpkg.cmake:85 (message):
  Unable to determine target architecture, continuing without vcpkg.
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  CMakeFiles/3.17.0/CMakeSystem.cmake:6 (include)
  CMakeLists.txt:4 (project)


CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:4 (project):
  Generator

    MinGW Makefiles

  does not support platform specification, but platform

    =Win32

  was specified.


CMake Error: CMAKE_C_COMPILER not set, after EnableLanguage
CMake Error: CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER not set, after EnableLanguage
-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
See also "D:/.WorkSpaces/KeyHUD/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".
```

Folder structure

```
D:\.WORKSPACES\KEYHUD
├───.vscode
├───build
├───CMakeFiles
│   └───3.17.0
|───raster
|───main.cpp
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! For being able to help you we need more **details** about your problem. Please. read [ask] and update your question post accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

You need to define `VCPKG_TARGET_TRIPLET` in your cmake call (probably x64-mingw) to avoid the warning and drop the `-A=Win32`

also `cmake -G "MinGW Makefile"` has a typo it should be `cmake -G "MinGW Makefiles"` (missing the s)

so try:

```
cmake -G "MinGW Makefiles" -DCMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE=D:\.Installs\vcpkg\scripts\buildsystems\vcpkg.cmake -DVCPKG_TARGET_TRIPLET=x64-mingw
```